# Application to slide from area to start application?

Tags: applications

I had an application before I formatted which would do something awesome: you simply slid from an active area on the screen, no matter what application you're in, and you were presented with about 12 different spots you could fill which would launch applications.

The problem is, I can't remember what this application is called. Can anyone remind me?

Comment: One thing you can do is log in to the android market web and go through your history of installed applications. It will show you everything that you installed (purchased and free)

Comment: Somehow, it's not there, believe me: I looked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwipePad. Found it: https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android